# How to write multiple valued dictionaries to csv using csv module?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, file-conversion, multivalue

```
import csv

dict = {'a':[1,4],'b':[2,3]}
```

I want to convert this module into a csv file with name 'rating.csv'

Desired Output:

```
name,maths,science
a,1,4
b,2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may iterate through your dictionary keys and values, join the two to a single list and then use [`csv.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) for each entry:

```
import csv
d = {'a':[1,4],'b':[2,3]}
with open("rating.csv", "w", newline="") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    writer.writerow(["name", "maths", "science"])
    for key, values in d.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + values)
```

Note that I have re-named `dict` to `d` as you should avoid using builtin names for your variables.

Output in "rating.csv":

```
name,maths,science                                                              
a,1,4                                                                           
b,2,3
```